# Two-Ray Ground-Reflection Model: Understanding the Difference in Phase Offsets at the Receiver

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, signal-processing

Currently, I'm trying to understand the Two-Ray Ground-Reflection Model.
During my research, I came across the following simplification expressing the received power as follows (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-ray_ground-reflection_model)):
[image]

The part that is not clear to me is $e^{-j\Delta\phi}$:
How is that derived from $e^{-j2\pi l/\lambda}$ and $e^{-j2\pi (x + x\prime)/\lambda}$?

I know that $\phi$ can be calculated with $\phi = 2\pi d/\lambda$, where $d$ is the distance between the transmitter and the receiver.

In the above equation, the ground-reflected path is expressed as $(x + x\prime)$ and $l$ is the direct line-of-sight path.

Moreover, the approximation only holds if the signal is "narrow band relative to the inverse delay spread $1/\tau$, so that $s ( t ) \approx s ( t − τ )$".

Why is that important?

Thank you for your answers in advance!